# Python: two lists influencing each other?

Tags: python, list, sorting

`.sort()` is not working as I expect it to. I intended to create a Python program that sorts two copies of the same array in ascending and descending order.

## Initial code

```py
def MyFunction(Num):
    StrNum = str(Num)
    ArrNum = [letter for letter in str(Num)]
    print(ArrNum)

    print('Ascending and Descending Arrangements')
    AscendingNum = ArrNum
    DescendingNum = ArrNum

    DescendingNum.sort(reverse=True)
    print(DescendingNum)
    AscendingNum.sort()
    print(AscendingNum)


MyFunction(1032)
```

## Result

`DescendingNum = ['3', '2', '1', '0']`

`AscendingNum = ['0', '1', '2', '3']`

I reprinted them.

## Result with ascending sorted last

`DescendingNum = ['0', '1', '2', '3']`

`AscendingNum = ['0', '1', '2', '3']`

## Result with descending sorted last

`DescendingNum = ['3', '2', '1', '0']`

`AscendingNum = ['3', '2', '1', '0']`

## My guess at why it is happening

It appears that the second sorting is affecting the first. Although I have read many articles on `.sort()`, I cannot grasp why this is happening; after all, they are two separate arrays. Yet, I feel that the reason might lie in the following part.

```py
    AscendingNum = ArrNum
    DescendingNum = ArrNum
```

What is the reason and solution?

Comment: `sort` changes your list in place and you are referring to the very same list in both cases. Either use `copy()` on the original list to generate a new one or use the `sorted()` function which will generate a new sorted list for you.

Comment: Because the issue is not with the sort. Both `AscendingNum` and `DescendingNum` point to same variable `ArrNum`, so change made to one reflects to the other.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? The question is clear, and there is a reproducible example. If you think it's too simple of a question, remember that you too started from somewhere

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Wasn't me but this question has been asked several times.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity It probably was downvoted for insufficient prior research, not because it's too simple. This issue of people not understanding they have one list with two names is a *very* common problem for people new to Python.

Comment: This may be helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), by Ned Batchelder. Also, [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411011411/http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Comment: BTW, we don't normally use CamelCase in Python for simple identifiers, we use it for class names. Please see the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 2):

> Yet, I feel that the reason might lie in the following part.

> AscendingNum = ArrNum
> DescendingNum = ArrNum

Indeed, if you also try to print `AscendingNum is DescendingNum`, you'll get `True`

---

If you want them to both be new objects, you could do

```
AscendingNum = list(ArrNum)
DescendingNum = list(ArrNum)
```

Comment: Just `AscendingNum = list(ArrNum)` would do here – no need to deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

it's not working cause on the second example you work on the same list object

this happens cause:

```
AscendingNum = ArrNum
DescendingNum = ArrNum
```

i would recommand (or using deepcopy):

```
AscendingNum = ArrNum.copy()
DescendingNum = ArrNum.copy()
```